# What is the difference between IBM Semeru and Adoptium

Tags: java, jvm, adoptopenjdk

I wanted to update my JDK, so I went to AdoptOpenJDK to download one. I saw that they have moved to Adoptium, and so I went over there. There I saw that there were no options to choose the JVM, and when I downloaded the installer, it was for Hotspot. I googled it, and I found IBM Semeru. Are these JDKs/JVMs different. Is there one which is significantly faster than the other? Does it even matter?

Comment: Adoptium/Semeru aren't the only options. There are also Oracle, Azul, Red Hat, Microsoft, Amazon (and probably others I missed).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's some discussion of the difference between the two from IBM over in https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/10666#issuecomment-894204729:

> Eclipse Temurin delivers OpenJDK + Hotspot images, and IBM Semeru Runtimes going forward will deliver both Open and Certified (JCKed) versions of OpenJDK + Eclipse OpenJ9 images.

> It is a confusing story and transition, I will try to add a bit of background.
> AdoptOpenJDK up until now was producing OpenJDK binaries with both Hotspot and OpenJ9 VM's. With Adopt's move to Eclipse, legal restrictions prevent the new Eclipse Adoptium group from producing/releasing OpenJ9 based binaries. As a result, IBM will be producing OpenJ9 based binaries in 2 flavours, Open and Certified, both under the family name IBM Semeru Runtimes. Essentially the same binaries, released under different licenses.

So I suppose what you'll want to be looking for is comparisons between Hotspot and OpenJ9 (and I imagine any speed differences between those would be somewhat workload dependent, but there are quite a few articles online that have done actual benchmarks, such as https://www.ojalgo.org/2019/02/quick-test-to-compare-hotspot-and-openj9/).